# Responsive search box, increase instead of overlapping

Tags: css

How can I make the search bar smaller instead of letting it overlap with the logo image or to make it width bigger when increasing the screen size?
At the moment it stays the same size at any screen I make.

My CSS:

```
  .header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background: white;
  }

  .header h1 {
      font-size: 30px;
      padding-right: 10px;
      width: 30%;
  }

  #search-bar {
      width: 60%;
      height: 40px;
      font-size: 1rem;
      border: 1px solid #D0CFCE;
      border-top-left-radius: 20px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  }

  #search-button {
      height: 40px;
      font-size: 1rem;
      border: 1px solid #D0CFCE;
      border-top-right-radius: 20px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  }

  .header form {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="header">
  <h1>
    <a href="home"><img src="" alt="Company Logo"></a>
  </h1>

  <form action="search">
    <input type="text" id="search-bar" placeholder="Search anything...">
    <button type="submit" id="search-button">Search</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```css
.header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background: white;
    max-width: 100%;
    gap: 10px;
  }

  .header h1 {
      font-size: 30px;
  }
  #search-bar {
      width: 10px;
      flex: 1;
      height: 40px;
      font-size: 1rem;
      border: 1px solid #D0CFCE;
      border-top-left-radius: 20px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  }

  #search-button {
      height: 40px;
      font-size: 1rem;
      border: 1px solid #D0CFCE;
      border-top-right-radius: 20px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  }

  .header form {
    display: flex;
    flex: 400px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>
    <a href="home"><img src="" alt="Company Logo"></a>
  </h1>

  <form action="search" id="form">
    <input type="text" id="search-bar" placeholder="Search anything...">
    <button type="submit" id="search-button">Search</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

We set a `max-width` on the `header` so it doesn't get wider than the screen:

```
.header {
   max-width: 100%;
   ...
}
```

We also give `search-bar` a `flex:1` and `width:10px` so that it will grow when it has room, but doesn't get smaller than 10px wide:

```
#search-bar {
      width: 10px;
      flex: 1;
      ...
  }
```

We also give the `form` a `flex: 400px` so that it can grow when it has room:

```
.header form {
    display: flex;
    flex: 400px;
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> use `vw` instead of giving fixed width
> checkout this code

```css
  .header {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background: white;
  }

  .header h1 {
      font-size: 30px;
      padding-right: 10px;
      display:block;
  }

  #search-bar {
      width: 60vw;
      min-width:200px;
      height: 40px;
      font-size: 1rem;
      border: 1px solid #D0CFCE;
      border-top-left-radius: 20px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  }

  #search-button {
      height: 40px;
      font-size: 1rem;
      border: 1px solid #D0CFCE;
      border-top-right-radius: 20px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  }

  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
  }
  
 
  form{
    display:flex; 
  }
```

```html
<div class="header">
<div class="wrapper">
 
  <h1>
    <a href="home"><img src="" alt="Company Logo"></a>
  </h1>

  <form action="search">
    <input type="text" id="search-bar" placeholder="Search anything...">
    <button type="submit" id="search-button">Search</button>
  </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

delete `width: 60%;` from `#search-bar` and add this:

```
#search-bar {
  flex: 1.5;
}

#search-button {
  flex: 1;
}

.header form {
  flex: 1;
}
```